# Unable to remove TeXLive 2016 from Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, dpkg, latex

I installed TeXLive 2016 via PPA and used following commands-

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/texlive
sudo apt update
sudo apt install texlive-full
```

Due to some reasons, I tried to remove it but I couldn't. Later, I installed TeXLive from the official website by following this link [Installing TeX Live over the Internet](https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html). I used the following command-

```
ravi@home:~/Downloads/install-tl-20180527$ sudo ./install-tl
```

Now, I am able to use TeXLive 2018 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS using `Texmaker 4.1 (compiled with Qt 4.8.4 and Poppler 0.24.3)`. However, my Ubuntu shows the following error-

[image]

It seems that TeXLive2016 is the culprit. I used `sudo apt-get purge texlive*` but it didn't work. Please see below-

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 asymptote : Depends: texlive-latex-base but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: texlive-base-bin
             Depends: texlive-pstricks but it is not going to be installed
 dvipng : Depends: texlive-base-bin
 feynmf : Depends: texlive-latex-base but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: texlive-font-utils but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: texlive-extra-utils but it is not going to be installed
 fragmaster : Depends: texlive-base-bin
              Depends: texlive-latex-base but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: texlive-latex-recommended but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: texlive-extra-utils but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: texlive-font-utils but it is not going to be installed
 latex-beamer : Depends: texlive-latex-base but it is not going to be installed
 latex-xcolor : Depends: texlive-latex-recommended but it is not going to be installed
 latexmk : Depends: texlive-latex-base but it is not going to be installed
 pgf : Depends: texlive-latex-recommended but it is not going to be installed
 prosper : Depends: texlive-latex-base but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: texlive-pstricks but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: texlive-latex-recommended but it is not going to be installed
 purifyeps : Depends: texlive-metapost but it is not going to be installed
 tex4ht-common : Depends: texlive-base-bin
                 Recommends: tex4ht but it is not going to be installed
 tipa : Depends: texlive-latex-base but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: texlive-base-bin
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Also tried `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get -f install`. Plese, see below-

```
ravi@home:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  luatex texlive-binaries texlive-extra-utils texlive-font-utils
  texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-fonts-recommended-doc
  texlive-generic-recommended texlive-latex-base
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  context
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  luatex texlive-binaries texlive-extra-utils texlive-font-utils
  texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-fonts-recommended-doc
  texlive-generic-recommended texlive-latex-base
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 1 to remove and 264 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/30.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 9,608 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 295461 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing context (2016.05.17.20160523-1~ubuntu14.04.1york0) ...
unknown option: format
dpkg: error processing package context (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 context
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any workaround to fix it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove PPA in correct way by using `ppa-purge` command. It will downgrade packages to the versions from official repository and only after this will remove corresponding file from */etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.

The commands you need to run are below:

```
#sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/texlive # add you PPA again if removed
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge # install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:jonathonf/texlive # downgrade packages
```

Then install TeXLive 2018 with:

```
cd ~/Downloads/install-tl-20180527
sudo ./install-tl
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am following your instructions. However,  I am not able to install `ppa-purge` using `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`. I have copied the logs to PasteBin. Please see [here](https://pastebin.com/JTLs8y1n)

Comment: How many packages do you have installed from PPA? Post output of  `dpkg -l | grep york` to pastebin.

Comment: Done.  Please have a look [here](https://pastebin.com/UuMhPpAg)

Comment: Try to remove PPA-packages with `sudo apt-get purge texlive-humanities-doc texlive-publishers-doc texlive-fonts-recommended-doc texlive-fonts-extra-doc context` .

Comment: Looks like I did it. Please see the logs [here](https://pastebin.com/8ZgKYQFH). Now, just making sure I haven't broken the OS!